# cpp programs run slow on server

Tags: python, c++, bash, server

I have a problem with running multiple c++ programs via a python script.
All processes are executing finely, and all process finishes with 0 error etc., but the processes are not running 100% on the CPU's.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, shutil, time, math

from sys import *

CPUs=64
shs={}
for i in range(CPUs):
    fname="run"+repr(i)+".sh"
    shs[i]=file(fname,"w")
    #print "nohup bash "+fname+" &"
    time.sleep(0.01)

fin = file("adatokOriginal.txt") 
lines = fin.readlines()
fin.close()


#    kezdpath = "./szimulaciok_n5_5240_"+str(n)+"/szimul_"+str(m)+"/instanc_"+str(l)
#    if(os.path.isdir(kezdpath)):
#   shutil.rmtree(kezdpath)
#    os.mkdir(kezdpath,0777)

for m in range (5):
    k=0
    for j in range(33):
    print(m,j)
    mu=10**(-6) * j**(math.log(10,2))
    for i in range (1000):
        fout = file("adatok.txt", "w+")
        Pathpath = "./szimulaciok_n5_5240"+"_"+str(m)+"/szimul"+"_"+str(j)+"/instanc_"+str(i)
        if (os.path.isdir(Pathpath)):
        shutil.rmtree(Pathpath)
        os.makedirs(Pathpath,0777)
            for line in lines:
        line=line.strip()
                if line == "outputDir= default": 
                #   fout.write("outputDir= "+str(path)+"/\n")
                    print("lel")
                elif line == "mutrata= 1":
                    fout.write("mutrata= "+str(mu)+"\n")
                elif line == "szintszam= 5":
                    n=5-m
                    fout.write("szintszam= "+str(n)+"\n")
                #elif line == "mutrata= 0.1":
                #   fout.write("mutrata= "+str(1)+"\n")
                else:
                    fout.write(line+"\n")
            fout.close()
            os.rename("./adatok.txt", Pathpath+"/adatok.txt")
            shutil.copyfile("./gnuplotscriptOriginal.plt", Pathpath+"/gnuplotscriptOriginal.plt")
k=0
for c in range(5):  
        for b in range(33):
        for a in range(1000):
            path = "./szimulaciok_n5_5240"+"_"+str(c)+"/szimul"+"_"+str(b)+"/instanc_"+str(a)
            shs[k%CPUs].write("cd "+path+"\n")
            shs[k%CPUs].write("../../../szimu >/dev/null\n")
            shs[k%CPUs].write("cd ../../..\n")
            k = k+1

for i in range(CPUs):
    shs[i].close()
for i in range(CPUs):
    fname="run"+repr(i)+".sh"   
    os.chmod(fname,0777)    
    os.system("./"+fname+"&\n")
    time.sleep(0.01)

print("ok")
```

I can run 64 processes simultaneously, where I have 5 times 33 times 1000 process to execute and run. The only problem is that I have average 45% CPU exploitage.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason of your low performance is your huge amount of I/O operation during each loop iteration. As I see in your code, in each iteration you are writing something in the file which requires access to disk. When OS is accessing the disk, the CPU is released for other usages which causes reduce in total performance of your application.
If you want to test your real CPU performance, it is enough to comment your IO commands and replace them with some CPU consuming operations such as calculation. Then measure your CPU usage.

Comment: No my bad... It is my mistake that I havent discussed my code properly. So in the first three loops (m,j,i) I make the directories needed for output data, with rewriting "adatok.txt "which is the input data for each folders cpp program (runs as "szimu"), which generates the output data. And just after I generated the folders with the proper input data, just after I am executing the cpp programs, 64 simultaniously with the c b a loop...

Comment: Another odd thing is that as I scroll down the performance decreases within the processes...

PrintScreen:http://imgur.com/YezwLWY